# Does the sequence $1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,\ldots$ have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

> **Question** : Can we represent the following sequence $\{a_n\}\ (n\ge 0)$ as a closed form?$$a_n : 1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,\ldots$$ Suppose that there exist ${(i+1)}$ $1_s$ between the $i_{th}$ $(-1)$ and ${(i+1)}_{th}$ $(-1)$ for $i=1,2,\cdots$.

Though I've thought about this, I'm facing difficulty. Can anyone help? A simpler form is better if closed forms exist.

**Motivation** : I've known that a periodic sequence can be represented as a closed form. For example, if a sequence $\{b_n\}\ (n\ge0)$ is defined as
$$b_n : 1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,\ldots,$$
(Suppose that $b_n=-1\ (n\equiv 4),b_n=1\ (n\not\equiv 4)\ ($mod$ 6$))

then we can represent $\{b_n\}$ as
$$b_n=\frac 13\left(2+(-1)^n+2\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}-2\cos\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right).$$
Then, I got interested in the above sequence $\{a_n\}$. I'm facing difficulty because $\{a_n\}$ is not periodic.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your definition of $\{a_n\}$ is describing (and we have two different interpretations above me). Can you please write out the first several terms of $\{a_n\}$ to make it clear what you intend, here?

Comment: @mathlove Just shift it by one. You want $1,11,111,1111,\ldots$?

Comment: @CameronBuie: Well, I can't what you mean. I've already written the first several terms. I meant that $a_0=1, a_1=-1, a_2=1$ and so on.

Comment: @mathlove Insert commas between the terms, then it is more clear what the terms are intended to be.

Comment: And delete the space between the minus sign and the 1.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I edited them.

Comment: It is strange that you first have two ones, then four, then five. Why not $-1$, two ones, $-1$, three ones, $-1$, four ones, &c?

Comment: Is there an analytic formula for the number of divisors of a number? Then you could have $(-1)^{d_0(8n+9)}$

Comment: This may be relevant: http://oeis.org/A023532

Comment: the URL for this is amusing: `math.stackexchange.com/questions/540379/does-the-sequence-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-ldots-have-a-c` :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$a_n=-(-1)^{\left\lceil\frac{-3+\sqrt{8n+9}}{2}\right\rceil-\left\lfloor\frac{-3+\sqrt{8n+9}}{2}\right\rfloor}.$$

or

$$a_n=-\cos\pi\left( {\left\lceil\frac{-3+\sqrt{8n+9}}{2}\right\rceil-\left\lfloor\frac{-3+\sqrt{8n+9}}{2}\right\rfloor} \right).$$

---

The basic idea of find this form is find a pattern of place of $-1$ occurs. By simple calculation, we can find that $-1$ occurs when $n=\frac{1}{2}k(k+1)+k$ for some $k$.

Let we find a function $f$ satisfy that $f(\frac{1}{2}(k^2+3k))$ is odd and otherwise $f(n)$ is even. If we can find this function we can define a sequence $a_n=(-1)^{f(n)}$. But we know that
$$
\lceil x\rceil -\lfloor x\rfloor =\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x$ is integer }\\ 1 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

and $\frac{1}{2}(n^2+3n)=x\Longleftarrow  x= \frac{-3+\sqrt{8x+9}}{2}$. In that case, $x$ is integer iff $x=\frac{1}{2}(k^2+3k)$ for some $k$. So if we define $f(n)=\lceil x\rceil -\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ then we get desired function.

Comment: Cool, it would be great if you gave a motivation though

Comment: Great! thank you very much.

Comment: @AndreasT I will add it.

Comment: Great solution! +1

Comment: I think your subscripts are out by one: the first element of the sequence is explicitly stated to be $a_0$, not $a_1$.

Answer (score 12):

To start with, we want a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow  \{0,1\}$ that can tell integers from non-integers. For instance:

$$f(x) = \lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor$$

which is $0$ or $1$ according as $x$ is an integer or not.

Next, we want a function $g:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that is an integer only when its argument is in $\{1,4,8,13,19,\ldots\}$ (i.e. when $a_n = -1$). For instance:

$$g(n)=\sqrt{8n+17}$$

Now it's easy: just take $a_n = 2f(g(n)) - 1$.

Comment: This is essentially the same as tetori's answer, but tetori was faster than me. I posted it anyway, because I think the motivation is clearer here.

Comment: ...and the function is simpler! +1